# Optimization of 3 Eloquent requests (1.5 seconds of request duration...)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I would like to optimize these 3 queries that allow me to display the users who have posted the most photos on our site, according to date criteria (current week, last week, since the beginning).

The query time is measured at 1.5 seconds with the debug bar, it's really long !
Do you know how to optimize it ?

```php
public function show()
{
    $currentWeek = User::whereHas('pictures')
        ->whereHas('pictures', fn ($q) => $q->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()]))
        ->withCount(['pictures' => fn ($q) => $q->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])])
        ->orderBy('pictures_count', 'DESC')
        ->limit(10)
        ->get();

    $lastWeek = User::whereHas('pictures')
        ->whereHas('pictures', fn ($q) => $q->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->subWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->subWeek()]))
        ->withCount(['pictures' => fn ($q) => $q->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->subWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->subWeek()])])
        ->orderBy('pictures_count', 'DESC')
        ->limit(10)
        ->get();

    $overall = User::whereHas('pictures')
        ->whereHas('pictures')
        ->withCount('pictures')
        ->orderBy('pictures_count', 'DESC')
        ->limit(10)
        ->get();

    return view('users.leaderboard', [
        'currentWeek' => $currentWeek,
        'lastWeek' => $lastWeek,
        'overall' => $overall,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: did you try creating `index` of database column 'created_at'?

Comment: no never, can you explain more ? :)

Comment: yes sure. indexes are exactly like how indexes are listed in the beginning of any book to find the items by their names on specific pages. Database uses indexes to do the same. for example you have a table containing 1,00,000 data and you query to search a name 'xyz'. So, in normal case the database will look for 'xyz' from start to end and will go through all 1,00,000 records to find 'xyz'. But if you create an index on 'name' column, then the database will only look where the name starts with 'x' and it will not need to look all 1,00,000 records and thus the query result will be much faster

Comment: try googling `mysql indexing for query optimization` for more info and how to create indexes

Comment: Oh ok I see ! Nice ! And do you think it's because there are so many records that it takes so long or are my queries just not optimized?

Comment: yes, more data needs more time to be accessed

Comment: Ok, thanks for you precious help and for your time ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, you've called `whereHas` twice on the pictures relationship, so you can get rid of the unqualified call.

```php
$currentWeek = User::whereHas('pictures', fn ($q) => $q->whereBetween('created_at', [now()->startOfWeek(), now()->endOfWeek()]))
    ->withCount(['pictures' => fn ($q) => $q->whereBetween('created_at', [now()->startOfWeek(), now()->endOfWeek()])])
    ->orderBy('pictures_count', 'DESC')
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

This reduces the SQL query from this:

```sql
select `users`.*, (
    select count(*) from `pictures` where `users`.`id` = `pictures`.`user_id` and `created_at` between ? and ? and `pictures`.`deleted_at` is null
) as `pictures_count`
from `users`
where exists (select * from `pictures` where `users`.`id` = `pictures`.`user_id` and `pictures`.`deleted_at` is null)
    and exists (select * from `pictures` where `users`.`id` = `pictures`.`user_id` and `created_at` between ? and ? and `pictures`.`deleted_at` is null)
    and `users`.`deleted_at` is null
    order by `pictures_count` desc
    limit 10
```

To this:

```sql
select `users`.*, (
    select count(*) from `pictures` where `users`.`id` = `pictures`.`user_id` and `created_at` between ? and ? and `pictures`.`deleted_at` is null
) as `pictures_count`
from `users`
where exists (select * from `pictures` where `users`.`id` = `pictures`.`user_id` and `created_at` between ? and ? and `pictures`.`deleted_at` is null)
    -- no second where exists clause
    and `users`.`deleted_at` is null
    order by `pictures_count` desc
    limit 10
```

Now, you've only got one condition in the `where` clause. It selects users that have pictures in the specified date range. Looks better, right?

---

But, you're already using `withCount` with a closure so you only count pictures in the date range. What happens if the condition doesn't match? It returns zero. Since you're reverse sorting by count anyway, the other call to `whereHas` can also go.

```php
$currentWeek = User::withCount(['pictures' => fn ($q) => $q->whereBetween('created_at', [now()->startOfWeek(), now()->endOfWeek()])])
    ->orderBy('pictures_count', 'DESC')
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

Now your SQL looks like this:

```sql
select `users`.*, (
    select count(*) from `pictures` where `users`.`id` = `pictures`.`user_id` and `created_at` between ? and ? and `pictures`.`deleted_at` is null
) as `pictures_count`
    from `users`
    where `users`.`deleted_at` is null
    -- no where exists clauses at all any more
    order by `pictures_count` desc
    limit 10
```

And it should run much faster. This does change your data somewhat; the resulting collection will always have 10 items, even if some of them are zero. If you don't want zeros in your leaderboard, just filter them out of the collection.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I will apply all this. I will apply all of this. Thank you!